# Hibernate/JPA : How to do the query that return the attribute of the DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have these 2 classes :

```
public class E1 {
     int id;
     E2 e;
     // getters and setters 
}

public class E2 {
    int id;
    // attributes, getters and setters
}
```

What would be the right JPA Query that will return the right E2 instance using E1 id attribute ?

```
E2 findE2ByE1Id(int E1Id)
{
    // which query here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a jpql query,you can use this method :

```
E2 findE2ByE1Id(int E1Id){

String queryString="SELECT e1.e2 FROM E1 e1 WHERE e1.id=:id";

Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString).setParameter("id",E1Id);

try{
    return query.getSingleResult();

 }catch(NoResultException e){
    System.out.println("No result found");
    return null;
 }
}
```

Hope this helps you

**EDIT :** Improved code to handle `NoResultException`.

Comment: This is the right answer +1. but how to manage the exception? Also, I'd like to know if any Fetching is necessary.

Comment: I updated my answer.You can handle no result exception.If jpa throw NoResultException,you should return null and print some info to log.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a query?
can't you just get E1 first and then get E2? like

```
E1 e1 = (E1) session.get(E1.class, E1.id);
E2 e2 = e1.getE2();
```

something like this?